# Hot to integrate sipJs and freeswitch?

Tags: sip, freeswitch

I am trying to integrate sipjs with freeswitch. below is the config I am using

```
var config = {
// Replace this IP address with your FreeSWITCH IP address
uri: 'sip:1002@***.***.1.170',

// Replace this IP address with your FreeSWITCH IP address
// and replace the port with your FreeSWITCH port
ws_servers: 'ws://***.***.1.170:5060',

// FreeSWITCH Default Username
authorizationUser: '1002',

// FreeSWITCH Default Password
password: '1234'
};
var userAgent = new SIP.UA(config);
```

....

```
session = userAgent.invite('sip:1000@***.***.1.170', options);
```

But getting following error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://***.***.1.170:5060/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
```

I have already modified internal.xml to allow web socket connections.
Could someone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect on port 5066 for ws or wss port 7443 .